# Draggable in Scrolled area with jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a `Draggable` and `Sortable` area and my Draggable area have scrollbar,when i try to drag item from draggable to sortable at first scroll area scrolled and this is not good and second when drag i dragging item i cant see the dragged item around the cursor. for more information i try to create a a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/IcehiNiC/1/edit?html,css,js,output) so my questions is :

1. when dragged from draggable area shoud not scroll
2. see dragg item around cursor

Answer (score 1):

You should give all elements width and height to prevent strange behaviour. Sortable won't work properly without it. To disable scrollbars use **overflow:hidden** . It's also good to diable the bullet points with **list-style-type: none** and give the draggables a background color to see them better. 
Use the  as container rather then the encapsulating . This is the usual way ... and the way to prevent problems.

You're using draggable(), dropable() and sortable() all mixed up together but for you case you really need only sortable().

**[The new code is here jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uhupAR/1)**

[image]

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="draggableContainer connectedSortable">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
       <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
       <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="droppableContainer connectedSortable">
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('.draggableContainer, .droppableContainer').sortable({
  connectWith:'.connectedSortable',
  cursor: "move", cursorAt: { top: 10, left: 60 },
  zIndex:999
}).disableSelection();
```

**CSS**

```
.droppableContainer{
  z-index:0;
}
.droppable, draggable{
  z-index:1000;
}

ul {
    padding:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
      width:100px;
      height:20px;
      margin-bottom:2px;
      background-color:silver
}

.draggableContainer, .droppableContainer{
  background-color:gray;
  width:120px;
  height:200px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  margin:0;
  display:inline-block;
}
.droppableContainer{
  background-color:violet;

}
```

Comment: @MBehtemam Was it useful to you?